# regex for query string, a single case or multiple case

Tags: regex

I have this string `?foo=bar&language=fr&bar=foo` or this string `?language=fr`

I want to capture (fr) so i did the below:

```
/language=(.*)(?:\&)?/
```

A link for the regex, https://regexr.com/440ga

Comment: E.g. `/language=([^&]*)/`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew :) I surely didn't know about that trick :)

Comment: @DjoryKrache you better test your comment/answer before